# Joi - validate a property based on value of other property

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I want to conditionally check the `os.disk_size` property based on the `image.offer` property.

If `image.offer` is `windows` then `os.disk_size>= 64` for all other cases `os.disk_size>=30`

Sample data below

```
{
    "resource": {
        "vms": {
            "v1": {
                "os": {
                    "disk_size": 30
                },
                "image": {
                    "offer": "ubuntu"
                },
            },
            "v2": {
                "os": {
                    "disk_size": 50
                },
                "image": {
                    "offer": "CentOS"
                }
            },
            "v3": {
                "os": {
                    "disk_size": 64
                },
                "image": {
                    "offer": "windows"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample validation:

I am using `"joi": "^13.1.2"`

```
const schemas = {
    resource: {    
        vms: Joi.object({
            image: Joi.object({
                offer: Joi.string().required()
            }).optional(),
            os: Joi.object({
                disk_size: Joi.number().required()
            }).required(),
        }),
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your schema is not considering object keys `v1`, `v2` and `v3`.

To consider those keys and follow the pattern `v + number`, you can use [Joi.pattern](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#objectpatternpattern-schema-options) with a regex `/v\d/`:

```
Joi.object().pattern(/v\d/, ...)
```

This means the key should start with a `v` and end with a number.

Then you can use [Joi.when](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#anywhencondition-options) combined with [ref](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#refkey-options) to achieve your condition:

```
Joi.object({
  resource: Joi.object({
    vms: Joi.object().pattern(
      /v\d/,
      Joi.object({
        image: Joi.object({
          offer: Joi.string().required(),
        }).optional(),
        os: Joi.object({
          disk_size: Joi.when(Joi.ref("...image.offer"), {
            is: "windows",
            then: Joi.number().min(64),
            otherwise: Joi.number().min(30),
          }),
        }).required(),
      })
    ),
  }),
});
```